# Identify window is closed using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have following link in my frame, this will open as new window, I want to know the open window is close or not, because I need to clear a cookie when user close the window.

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask" target="_blank">study plan new wndow</a>
```

Comment: Is that the real link ? i.e. Are you opening a page you own/control/can modify or is the link pointing to the outside world ?

Comment: no, real link is same domain with frame set

Comment: This link is SSO logging link, its redirect to some 3rd party page

Comment: Do you want to be able to tell if the window is still open, or do you want to react when it is closed?  They're two very different things.

Comment: That changes the potential answers, you should include the real code

Answer (score 1):

html:

```
<a href="#" onclick="myWinOpen(); return false;">study plan new wndow</a>
```

JS:

```
function myWinOpen()
{
    var w = window.open('http://same-domain.com/page.html');
    w.onbeforeunload = function()
    { 
        // my code..
    }
}
```

Comment: NOTE: popup url must be in the same domain of the parent

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onunload=function(){/*SomeJavaScriptCode*/};
```

OR

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (){/*your Cookie clear code here*/}
```